# Cannot use instance member 'pdfName' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to open up a pdf that matches the name of the row selected in a list but I am getting the error `Cannot use instance member 'pdfName' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available`.

I have tried initialising the variable name I am passing through between views but having no luck. I know this is simple but I always get confused when passing data.

Here is the `UIButton` in the first view

```
@State var showingDetail = false

ForEach(0..<product.applicationNotes.count, id: \.self) { item in
                Button(action: {
                    self.showingDetail.toggle()
                }) {
                    Text(product.applicationNotes[item])
                }.sheet(isPresented: $showingDetail) {
                    PDFKitView(pdfName: product.applicationNotes[item])
                }
```

And here is the second view where I am trying to pass the data to. I am getting the error on the second line `documentURL`:

```
    var pdfName: String
    var documentURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: pdfName, withExtension: "pdf")!
    var body: some View{ PDFViewer(url: documentURL) .ignoresSafeArea(edges:.bottom) }  }

struct PDFViewer: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    var url: URL
    func makeUIView(context:
        UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFViewer>) -> PDFViewer.UIViewType {
        let pdfView = PDFView()
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: self.url)
        return pdfView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFViewer>) {
    }
}
```

This is what I am trying to do to initialise it but dont know where I am going wrong:

```
 init() {
    self.pdfName = self.documentURL()
 }
```

Comment: I think this question has a straightforward answer, but I think a minimal (or at least 'locally complete') example would be helpful. You posted some code fragments, but it's not immediately clear (to me at least) what goes where and how they relate. Perhaps you could edit the post to make the example a little easier to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems:

1. you are initializing documentURL with the pdfName property right above it, that is a no-no in a SwiftUI Struct. That is the error you are getting.

   var documentURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: pdfName, withExtension: "pdf")!
2. in the init method you are assigning a URL property back to the pdfName String property.

   self.pdfName = self.documentURL()

SwiftUI already has setup an init for the pdfName property, get rid of the init and the documentURL property and try this:

```
struct PDFKitView {
    var pdfName: String
    
    var body: some View {
        PDFViewer(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: self.pdfName, withExtension: "pdf")!)
            .ignoresSafeArea(edges:.bottom)
    }
}
```

Its not ideal but will get you past the issue of trying to initialize a Struct property with the value of another Struct property. Look at .onAppear() as a better way to setup secondary properties. I wouldn't suggest doing resource fetch in an init method anyways, onAppear would be a better place.

Comment: This is great, thanks for in-depth explanation of where I went wrong!